# Static Polymorphism explained

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Here is a code I have got from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/603818/Cplusplus-Runtime-Polymorphism-without-Virtual-Fun):

```
class Deletor {
    public:  virtual ~Deletor() {}
};

template<typename T> class Base : public Deletor {
    public: 

        int  Run() { return static_cast<T*>(this)->DoIt(); }
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1> {
    ...
    public:
        int  DoIt() { /* the actual implementation for Derived1 */  }
};

class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2> {
    ...
    public:
        int  DoIt() { /* the actual implementation for Derived2 */  }
};

int main() {
    Derived1 Obj1;
    Derived2 Obj2;

    Obj1.Run(); /* runs the actual DoIt() implementation */
    Obj2.Run(); /* runs the actual DoIt() implementation */
};
```

I look and this code and think why I ned to use inheritance or CRTP to achieve this? I could just write two unrelated classes that both implement `Run()` method. What I miss here?

Answer (score 1):

It gets interesting when `Run` does other things besides just calling `DoIt`, and `DoIt` is just a customization point. So basically,`Run` is a complicated operation, with small variations. Those variations are achieved by various `DoIt` functions in the different subclasses, while the bulk of the code is shared.

For example, the base class could be a helper to implement smart pointers. That requires quite a bit of boilerplate code (the *, ->, !, ==, !=, and bool conversion operators), which all really come down to the single question of "give me a raw pointer", usually called `get()`. It's possible to share all this boilerplate in a CRTP base and only implement `get()` in the derived classes.